# Splitting region of interest iteratively with python and populating list of latitudes

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nested, coordinates

I'm running a python script that calls a json endpoint of coordinates. Since there is a feature limit, I have to split my bounding box vertically into several smaller parts. I want to achieve this iteratively, like this diagram
[image]

Starting with the whole region of interest, the features exceed the limit (10 in this example). The region is then split exactly in half (easy to do so mathematically), and each half is checked. The bottom half has more than 10, so is split again, and lastly, the 2nd quarter is split one last time, resulting in 4 regions, each with its own bounds that I can then input in my query.

Question is, how do I perform this?

I thought about using a nested list, with the 1st order being regions, and the 2nd being pairs of top and bottom, like this for the example above

```
latitudes = [[16,8],[8,6],[6,4],[4,0]]
```

Which I can thereafter iterate.

So how would I go about adding pairs to the list, and specifically, add them in the correct order from north to south?

I should add, the exact number of features and their distribution varies, so the total number of the region may be between 1 and about 8.

Comment: Recursion to the rescue : send a region, if it succeeds, return said region, otherwise, split it in halves, and call recursively the try/split on each half.

Answer (score 0):

Using a recursive function, you can check for a given subset wether it has more than 10 elements. If it has not, then the subset doesn't need to be split. Otherwise, you divide the subset in halves and perform the same operation.

You can implement this as follows:

```
data_points = [2, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

def compute_cover(points, offset=0):
    if sum(points) <= 10 or len(points) == 1:
        return [(offset, offset + len(points))]
    else:
        half = len(points) // 2
        return compute_cover(points[0:half], offset) + compute_cover(points[half:], offset + half)

print(compute_cover(data_points))
```

will output

```
[(0, 4), (4, 6), (6, 8), (8, 16)]
```